# Is a nanocomputer something a civilization would strive to create?

Tags: technology, technological-development, science-in-society, nanotechnology, scientific-development

I've recently been very interested in the concept of a nanocomputer for my future sci-fi world; as of now it's purely hypothetical/sci-fi esque. It seems cool, but I still have trepidations with it a little bit. What could it be used for? Would it be useful in a technologically advanced society or is it unnecessary?

Comment: ...And what exactly do you mean by "nanocomputer"? Commonly used modern transistors (the basic constituents of computation) are already only a dozen or so nanometers thick. More advanced ones can be as small as a few nanometers only.

Comment: Meh.  I'm an electrical engineer.  Scientists are successfully building 1-3nM transistor gates... one at a time.  We're decades away (if even that) from mass production.  Common silicon chips are still 100nM-1uM.  Besides, when the OP said "nancomputer" I assumed he meant what he said.  the whole computer that size.  Not just one transistor.

Comment: @JBH, the smallest feature in present state of the art mass produced IC is now 14 nm and soon to become 7 nm.

Comment: This question really needs more fleshing-out. As it stands, it's anyone's guess what is meant here. Yet it might become an interesting question if some more work was put in it. Oh, and welcome to worldbuilding! May i recommend to youu the [tour] and [help]?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Max. Your question may be on-topic, but we are having trouble identifying the problem you need solved. If you would [edit] your post to provide clarification on what a nanocomputer is, the community would appreciate it. Until such clarification is provided, this question will remain on hold.

Answer (score 4):

Dude... Back in the late 80s when hard drives were first capable of storing entire libraries of knowledge people actually thought that we'd need nothing more than that.  (a) An economy is driven by sales, and sales are driven by "better, faster".  (b) No engineer worth his or her salt can stand leaving things alone.  We're designed and, frankly, wired to build new things.  (c) No matter what you do with a computer, there's always something more you want to do.  Virtually none of today's video games can be run on computers even 15 years old.

Think of what spy agencies could do with AI the size of a fly.  Think of what control you'd have if individual cogs in a motor could detect for themselves wear and tear.  Think of the possibility of not just storing, not just accessing, but intelligently organizing and collating information --- entire planets worth of information.  And Dick Tracey's video watch?  Talk about *antique*.  And that's not asking questions like, if you could store a modern library worth of information with all the computational power necessary to manipulate it and interface it on something smaller than a BB, what could you do if you implanted that sucker in the human brain?

Oh, yeah.  Any society capable of building a computer would want nanocomputing.

Now, having said that, there are limitations if those computers are still using electricity.  Nano is 10^-9.  An angstrom is 10^-10.  Molecules are measured in angstroms.  Nano computing has its limit with electricty when (for example) your silicon-based MOSFET transistors have a gate with only 3-5 atoms wide.  You get to the point where you can't isolate the signal and maintain its integrity.  However, our technology isn't near that... yet.  And that assumes we don't come up with quantum computing ([check this out](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/subatomic-logic/)).

Answer (score 1):

[K Eric Drexler](http://www.nanoindustries.com/nanojbl/NanoConProc/nanocon2.html) actually described the theoretical basis of a nano computer in "Engines of Creation", so the idea has been around for a long time.

The actual advantage of such a nano computer simply has to do with the sheer size of the thing, it was described as a "rod logic" device and required the movements of "rods" of stiff atomic structures on the order of one atom's length to register a "1" or a "0".

As you can imagine, if the computations only require the shifting of an atom to change the register, then computation become blindingly fast. Nano computers would be many orders of magnitude faster than even the fastest electronic device, not to mention far smaller. A single cell would theoretically house a number of these devices, and you could have the equivalent of hundreds of supercomputers implanted in your skin.

Obviously the user interface and input/output devices would be a bit problematic between you and computers which are smaller than a human cell, but any high tech society will be interested in performing computations as rapidly as possible.

Comment: This book is from `86 and predates most of current knowledge of quantum mech. So it is a proof that idea is old, but treat any conclusions with a grain of salt. Or a bucket of salt, really.

Comment: @Molot, while true, the concept of highly miniturized electronics predates even '86.  One of my favorite authors, Jack Vance, implied it (in that everything was ultra-miniturized) in his Demon Princes stories (early 60's) and Asimov's *Foundation* trilogy (early 50's) depended on it.  Authors have been expressing the premise of the idea for at least 70 years.  Assuming that "nanocomputer" demands the premise of modern quantum computing denies the most valuable of an author's resources: imagination.